# How to pipe data through multiple processes?

Tags: process, call-process, pipe

Currently I'm generating text from a command, eg:

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (call-process "my-command" nil t nil "my" "args")
  ;; operate on output in current buffer.
  )
```

How can I use pipes, something that would be written in shell like this:

`my-command my args | wc -l`

---

*Note, this is just an example command, doing the same operation without pipes wont address this question.*

Answer (score 2):

Use the system shell, e.g., `M-! ls | wc`, there are many other APIs such as `shell-command-to-string`, `call-process-shell-command` and `start-process-shell-command`.

An idea is emulating pipe like the following, it is slow since the second process won't run until the first is done. Though it's possible to use asynchronous process + process filter to avoiding blocking, it's still going to be slow. (Take Eshell for example)

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (call-process "date" nil t)
  (call-process-region nil nil "wc" nil t t )
  (buffer-string))
;; =>
"Tue Apr  7 15:49:17 CST 2020
       1       6      29
"
```

Comment: Can't this be done without using the buffer as an intermediate step?

Comment: @ideasman42 It seems possible using asynchronous process, you get output from process with `process-filter`, and send input to process with `process-send-string`, both of them uses string.

Comment: A third option is to create temporary files and pass them as the second and third arguments to `call-process`. Apart from potentially being faster than using an Emacs buffer, though, I don't see any other benefits to this approach.

Comment: @Basil that's only an option if the process accepts the input as an argument, which isn't always the case.

Comment: @ideasman42 Specifying a file as the stdout of one process and the stdin of another, which the second and third arguments to `call-process` allow, has nothing to do with what arguments the process accepts.